# Let $M$ be an $A$-module. Prove that $\operatorname{Hom}_A(A,M) \cong M$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, commutative-algebra, modules, module-isomorphism

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> Let $M$ be an $A$-module. Prove that $\operatorname{Hom}_A(A,M) \cong M$.

I am wondering if the homomorphism that I should show is a group homomorphism or module homomorphism? Also, is my proof of injectivity and surjectivity correct?

Let  $f \colon \operatorname{Hom}_A(A,M) \rightarrow M$ be given by  $f(\phi) = \phi(1)$.

##### First. Showing that $f$ is a module homomorphism.

Let $\varphi, \psi $ be $A$-module homomorphisms from $A \to M$, i.e., $\varphi, \psi  \in \operatorname{Hom}_A(A,M),$ then $$f(\varphi + \psi) = (\varphi + \psi)(1) = \varphi (1) + \psi(1) = f(\varphi) + f(\psi) \,.$$

Let $r \in A$, and let $\psi \in \operatorname{Hom}_A(A,M)$, then $$f(r \psi ) = r \psi(1) = r f(\psi) \,.$$

##### Second. Showing that $f$ is injective.

Assume that $f(\varphi) = f(\psi)$ then $\varphi(1) = \psi(1)$ and knowing that a module homomorphism from $A$ to $M$ is completely determined by the image of $1$ then we can deduce that $\varphi = \psi$ as required.

##### Third. Showing that $f$ is surjective.

Let $m \in M$, define an $A$-module homomorphism $\varphi \colon A \to M$ by $\varphi (1) = m$, we can do this because a module homomorphism from $A$ to $M$ is completely determined by the image of $1$. Therefore, $f(\varphi) =  \varphi (1) = m$ as required.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141434/discussion-on-question-by-mathignorance-let-m-be-an-a-module-prove-that-o).